# VB .NET comparing strings

Tags: vb.net, string

I don't get what's going on. The method equals doesn't work, and neither comparing the strings with the '=' operator or with 'string.compare'. thetruth is always set as "false".

```
Public Function ProcessLabel(myValue As Object) As String
    If ((myValue Is DBNull.Value) = False) Then
        Dim thetruth As Boolean
        Dim myValueStr As String
        myValueStr = CStr(myValue)
        thetruth = String.Equals(myValueStr, "01/01/1900")
    End If
    Return myValue.ToString
End Function
```

I cannot attach images but I assure you, in myValueStr I have "01/01/1900".

Comment: Provide an example about how you call this function, and take a look at your return line .. it is not logical.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that `myValue` is a `Date` object and not a string and that a database is involved where the minimum value is `01/01/1900`, for example the `SMALLDATETIME` datatype.  If you look at it in debugger you see it like `01/01/1900`. But if you execute `ToString`( internally used on `CStr(myValue)`) you get the localized representation including the time portion, so something like  `01.01.1900 00:00:00` (f.e. in germany).

Instead compare the right types:

```
If Not myValue Is DBNull.Value AndAlso Not myValue Is Nothing Then
    Dim date = DirectCast(myValue, Date)
    If date = New Date(1900, 01, 01) Then 

    End If
End If
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the problem is with the time as you say, still the solution you've proposed doesn't work.
I've also tried to convert the date with ToShortDateString(), but again it fails when comparing with the string "01/01/1900".

Comment: @NicolaNonnis: `ToShortDateString` also converts the date to a LOCALIZED string representation.   And you can use `ToShortDateString` on dates only not on strings. So you have to cast or convert it to `Date` before you can use that method. But don't compare strings but the real type. What doesn't work, can you cast it to `Date`? Have you used the debugger? What is the value of `date` at the line `If date = New Date(1900, 01, 01) Then`? Set a breakpoint there and expect the value in the quick watch window.